# Problem with Linq query and date format

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a C# console application written using Visual Studio 2008.

My system culture is en-GB. I have a Linq query that looks like this:

```
var myDate = "19-May-2010";

var cus = from x in _dataContext.testTable
     where x.CreateDate == Convert.ToDateTime(myDate)
     select x;
```

The resulting SQL query generates and error because it returns the dates as "19/05/2010" which it interprets as an incorrect date. For some reason even though my system culture is set to en-GB it looks like it's trying to intrepret it as a en-US date.

Any ideas how I get around this?

Edit: Thanks for the comments about magic strings and var abuse, but that's not my problem. My problem is that in the conversion from Linq to SQL the dates are being interpreted as US format dates (19/05/2010 is being interpreted as: month nineteen, day 5 and year 2010) resulting in the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value
```

The where clause of the resulting SQL query looks like:

```
WHERE ([t0].[CreateDate] = '19/05/2010 00:00:00')
```

Please note that the exact same Linq query works perfectly in LinqPad.

I've tried the following where clause:

```
where x.CreateDate == DateTime.Today
```

and still get the error.

Additional Information:

SQL Server Query Visualizer:

```
SELECT [t0].[field1], [t0].[field2], [t0].[field3] AS [field4], [t0].[field5]
FROM [dbo].[table] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CreateDateTime] = '19/05/2010 00:00:00') 

Original query:
SELECT [t0].[field1], [t0].[field2], [t0].[field3] AS [field4], [t0].[field5]
FROM [dbo].[table] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CreateDateTime] = @p0) 
-------------------------------
@p0 [DateTime]: 19/05/2010 00:00:00
```

---

LINQPad:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime SET @p0 = '2010-05-19 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[field1], [t0].[field2], [t0].[field3] AS [field4], [t0].[field5]
FROM [table] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CreateDateTime] = @p0)
```

In the above I notice that LinqPad presents the date in a different format to VS.

Thanks.

Alan T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send local strings into the database and ask the database to convert those strings into DateTimes.  Just don't.

Originally:

```
var myDate = "19-May-2010"; 

var cus = from x in _dataContext.testTable 
  where x.CreateDate == Convert.ToDateTime(myDate) 
  select x;
```

- Don't abuse var.
- Separate actions you intend to occur in the database from actions you intend to occur locally

So...

```
string myInput = "19-May-2010";
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myInput);

IQueryable<TestTable> cus =
  from x in _dataContext.testTable
  where x.CreateDate == myDate
  select x;
```

---

In response to the update.

- It seems that your app is sending the rightly formatted date times, but it's using a connection that expects wrongly formatted datetimes.
- You can change each connection or you can change the login's defaults: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907

Comment: Hi David, I tried you suggestion and still got the error. I've added more information to my question.

Comment: Hi Daivd, Thanks for the link. I don't want to set anything at a database level as there are other databases running. As for login defaults, I changed the language for the user from English to British English with no joy. With regard to the per connection, I don't know how to achive this via Linq. I think the database server is the issue as I get the same errors when running the SQL version of the query on both a development and live server.

Comment: var makes the code less readable.  If you start reading from the query, you can see that myDate is used.  If you want to know the type of myDate, you need to look at its declaration.  The declaration doesn't tell you so now you need to look at its initialization.  Instead, the first programmer could have put the types in and saved the compiler and all future programmers one more step of reasoning.

Comment: You can just mouse over var and VS tells you.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "don't use strings to represent dates".

Assuming the CreateDate column is a SQL Server datetime, you should be able to just do your compare with a .NET DateTime class.

Comment: If you really do need to accept input as a string and convert it, use dcp's snippet. If you don't absolutely need to use strings, avoid it.

Comment: Hi Bill, I started out with DateTime.Now.Date and had the same issues. Strings were my second attempt. Interestingly, if I put the string in the where clause it works!

Comment: That's strange, but I guess under the covers when linq builds the actual sql query it is outputting the date string as en-US instead of en-GB. It would be interesting to see the output sql for doing a date to date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
x.CreateDate == DateTime.ParseExact(myDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This assumes, of course, that your date in the DB matches your myDate field (i.e. if you have time included with the date, you will need to modify the above to include the time portion).

Comment: Hi dcp, I tried your suggestion and still got the error. I've added the error details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill said, don't use strings to represent dates. LINQ to SQL uses parameterized queries to pass parameters so you shouldn't have any problems with locales - provided that your database field and your parameter are *both* dates.

You can check the generated SQL statement by attaching a TextWriter objec (like Console.Out) to the DataContext's Log property.The following code

```
using(var datacontext=new DatesDataContext())
{
    var myDate=DateTime.Today;
    //Or, to specify a date without string parsing
    //var myDate=new DateTime(2010,6,16);
    var dates = from date in datacontext.DateTables
        where date.DateField == myDate                 
        select date;

    datacontext.Log = Console.Out;
    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date.DateField);
    }
}
```

produced this query

```
SELECT [t0].[DateField]
FROM [dbo].[DateTable] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[DateField] = @p0
-- @p0: Input DateTime (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [6/16/2010 12:00:00 AM]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

As you see, the query has a parameter of type DateTime and returned the proper entries.

What exactly is the error you encounter? Do you get an exception or do you get incorrect results? 
If you get no results perhaps your database field contains a time value, in which case it won't match a parameter that contains only a date value

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, I get the following error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Comment: Can you post the entire statement generated by LINQ to SQL, including the provider comments? LINQ always uses parameterized queries to pass parameters. It shouldn't have created the WHERE statement you already posted.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, I've added more info to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try this

```
var myDate = "20100519"; 

var cus = from x in _dataContext.testTable 
     where x.CreateDate == Convert.ToDateTime(myDate) 
     select x;
```

Comment: Hi Madhivanan, I got the following error: "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid"

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably checked this, but can you verify the following:

1. CreateDate is declared as a DateTime or DateTime2 in the database
2. The CreateDate property in your Linqed class is declared as a .NET DateTime
3. The System.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute is defined properly on your CreateDate property in your Linqed up class.

Based on the fact that you're seeing success with the query in LinqPad, I suspect that there's something wrong with the CreateDate property or the SQL definition of that field.  I'm REALLY suspicious that your Linq-to-SQL output says "WHERE ([t0].[CreateDate] = '19/05/2010 00:00:00')" instead of "WHERE ([t0].[CreateDate] = @p0)".

Comment: Hi mattmc3, I've added more info to my question.